# How to change the color of lightning spinner?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

[image]

```
<div class="demo-only" style="height: 6rem;">
 <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium">
   <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
   <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
  <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

I need to change the color of Spinner into Blue color. Currently, it is showing in Gray color.

Or if anyone Have this blue color gif image which is rotating at the center of the page, please share me the link where can I download

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the brand class as well, as mentioned in [Spinners](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/spinners/).

```
<div class="demo-only" style="height: 6rem;">
 <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium slds-spinner_brand">
   <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
   <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
  <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
```