# how to change lightning-spinner color by overriding css

Tags: lightning, css, shared-css

I have to change the lighting-spinner color to RED.
If u know please Help.
Thank you!

```
.slds-spinner_large.slds-spinner:before, .slds-spinner_large .slds-spinner__dot-a:before, .slds-spinner_large .slds-spinner__dot-b:before, .slds-spinner--large.slds-spinner:before, .slds-spinner--large .slds-spinner__dot-a:before, .slds-spinner--large .slds-spinner__dot-b:before {
    animation-name: dotsBounceBefore-medium;
    top: -.3125rem;
    left: -.3125rem;
}
.slds-spinner_large.slds-spinner:before, .slds-spinner_large.slds-spinner:after, .slds-spinner_large .slds-spinner__dot-a:before, .slds-spinner_large .slds-spinner__dot-b:before, .slds-spinner_large .slds-spinner__dot-a:after, .slds-spinner_large .slds-spinner__dot-b:after, .slds-spinner--large.slds-spinner:before, .slds-spinner--large.slds-spinner:after, .slds-spinner--large .slds-spinner__dot-a:before, .slds-spinner--large .slds-spinner__dot-b:before, .slds-spinner--large .slds-spinner__dot-a:after, .slds-spinner--large .slds-spinner__dot-b:after {
    width: .625rem;
    height: .625rem;
}
.slds-spinner__dot-a:before {
    animation-delay: 83.33333ms;
}
.slds-spinner:before, .slds-spinner:after, .slds-spinner__dot-a:before, .slds-spinner__dot-b:before, .slds-spinner__dot-a:after, .slds-spinner__dot-b:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: var(--lwc-colorBackgroundSpinnerDot,rgb(176, 173, 171));
    border-radius: var(--lwc-borderRadiusCircle,50%);
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

--lwc-colorBackgroundSpinnerDot is not present in module while it is showing on the inspect page of the spinner component.

Comment: Are you going with lighting spinner slds tags or standard `lightning-spinner` tag from LWC?

Comment: Standard lightning-spinner tag.

Comment: You may need to convert that to slds tags so that you have control over the elements and you can change the color.
try this : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/250850/45062

Answer (score 1):

It has been solved!
Thanks for the comments.

```
 <template>
    <div class="example">
    <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" variant="brand" size="large" ></lightning-spinner>
</div>
</template>

    .example{
  position:relative;
  --lwc-brandPrimary: rgb(218 35 54);
  height: 80px;
}
```